# How to use search on rails, use gem ransack?

Tags: search, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a app about hotel, I have a model Room, RoomType:

room.rb

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: {freeing: true, using: false}

  belongs_to :room_type
```

room_type.rb

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
has_many :rooms
```

I want to search room through roomtype and I did in filter_form:

```
<%= form_tag admin_rooms_path, method: :get do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag t(".room_directory") %>
    <%= text_field_tag :number_or_room_types_name_cont,
      params[:number_or_room_types_name_cont],
      class: "form-control" %>
 </div>
```

or I try to work:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag t(".room_type") %>
    <%= select_tag :room_types_name_cont, options_for_select(@supports.room_types, params[:room_types_name_cont]),
    {include_blank: true, class: "form-control"} %>
</div>
```

and in room_support.rb:

`def room_types
    @room_types ||= RoomType.all.map{|room_type| [room_type.name, 
      room_type.id]}
   end`

controller I have a search_params:

```
def search_params
    params.permit :number_or_room_types_name_cont,
     :status_eq, :max_people_gteq
end
```

But it not work for me. Hope that everyone helpe me!
Thanks so much.

Comment: Sorry, at room_type.rb:                                                                                   `class RoomType < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :rooms

 validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
 
 validates :from_price, numericality: true
 validates :description, presence: true, length: {minimum: 20}
end`

Comment: Please edit your answer instead of commenting.

Comment: So sorry, but I don't know how to edit my answer, so that I used comment!.